# Not able to delete Azure Policy assignment using Azure commands in Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

I'm stuck on this issue for 2 days now but i don't seem to be able to delete Policy Assignments using Azure powershell commands or az commands.

All commands execute successfully and i am able to list all the assignments. The az delete command also executes successfully but does not delete the assignments, as they are still present in the Azure Portal policies.

Tried the following Powershell script:

```
$ResourceGroup = "PoliciesTest"
$query = "assignment"

# List policy assignments and extract the name and id
$assignments = az policy assignment list --resource-group $ResourceGroup --output json --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.name -like "*$query*" }

# Iterate through the assignments and display name and id
foreach ($assignment in $assignments) {
    Write-Host "Name: $($assignment.name)"
    Write-Host "ID: $($assignment.id)"
    Write-Host "--------------------"
    az policy assignment delete --name $assignment.name --scope $assignment.id  --debug

}
```

[result of executing the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1wgT.png)

There is one question on Stack overflow that has the same issue, but his issue was fixed by giving the scope. His solution does not work for me.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you run the ```az``` command in a regular non-powershell command prompt? As a test, try removing the ```--only-show-errors``` switch and add the ```--debug``` switch - tha'tll give you a *lot* more output and you might be able to find an error message in there somewhere to point to what the problem is...

Comment: @mclayton, same behavior when running the delete command in CMD. I let the command run with the debug option but it just gives me return 204 which usually means that it succeeded, but the assignments are still in the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not able to delete Azure Policy assignment using Azure commands in Powershell

If you get a `204` response when you try to delete an `Azure Policy` assignment, it might take some time for the portal to remove it from the display. To verify, run the `$assignments` variable.

I have below policy assignments with `venkat` name in portal before running PowerShell code.

[image]

```
$scope = "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-xxxxfjgjgj-b5ba-2bfhn4n5n6n"
$query = "venkat"
$assignments = az policy assignment list --scope $scope --output json --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.displayName -like "*$query*" }

foreach ($assignment in $assignments) {
$name= $assignment.name
Write-Host "Name: $($name)"
$scopeid = $assignment.id
Write-Host "ID: $($scopeid)"
Write-Host "--------------------"
az policy assignment delete --name $name   
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

After running the above code, the policy assignment was successfully deleted from the portal.

[image]

This script will remove the scope of the policy assignment: `Resource group`.

```
$scope = "/subscriptions/b83xxxxx-xxxxx-44fb-xxxx-2b83aabcdgfc23f/resourceGroups/venkat"
$query = "allowed"
$assignments = az policy assignment list --scope $scope --output json --only-show-errors | ConvertFrom-Json | Where-Object { $_.displayName -like "*$query*" }
foreach ($assignment in $assignments) {
$name= $assignment.name
Write-Host "Name: $($name)"
$resourcegroup = $assignment.resourceGroup
Write-Host "Resource Group: $($resourcegroup)"
Write-Host "--------------------"
az policy assignment delete --name $name --resource-group $resourcegroup
}
```

Comment: Hello @Venkat V, your code worked for removing the assignment i had on subscription level. On resource group level, the assignments don't get removed after changing the $scope to the Resource group like this: $scope = "/subscriptions/e142501e-XXXX-4cea-9fbd-461a3cf7370a/resourcegroups/PoliciesTest/". You have any idea on what action i can perform now?

Comment: Hi @robtje, I have updated the answer with a script that can remove the policy assignment scope for Resource Groups. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: you are a god, it's working now!